# Using ES5 shim with jquery/mootools/prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5, shim

I stumbled across this project: https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM which provides almost full ES5 support in all browsers including old IEs.

I've been using it in pure JS projects, but now I *have* to include jquery/mootools/prototype in a project (that uses High Charts).

Even just including the jquery script causes errors to be thrown in IE8 along with this shim. How can I keep the best of both worlds?

My document head looks like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="/js/a.ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="/js/a.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your `main.js` file doing? Where do you get an error, and which one? I've left my crystal ball at home.

Comment: @Bergi My main.js is empty for now. The error is: `Object doesn't support this property or method - a.ie8.js, line 46 character 428`

Comment: So, what is line 46 of that file (and its context)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the correct html structure, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="a.ie8.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="a.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

When I tested your structure (without doctype) I was also getting an error in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, and probably it doesn't address your main issue. So at the risk of getting downvoted...

As far I can tell from the Github project ES5-DOM-SHIM not only provides shim for ES5 features but also tries to shim DOM features that are not available on IE. This is very useful if you wish to program directly with the DOM API.

jQuery also provides a compatibility layer that does feature check in order to fill implementation gaps (so you don't need a DOM polyfill if your code only uses jQuery).

Mixing both doesn't seem to be a good idea because:

- You are duplicating a lot of polyfill logic in your JS.
- Polyfill have limitations, so if jQuery thinks that your browser fully supports a feature when it doesn't you can get some unexpected errors.

If you want JavaScript polyfills only, try with https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim (note ES5-DOM-SHIM is based on it)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to add a doctype to your HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It has to be on the first line of your HTML file(s). That makes old IE to work in standards compliant mode and avoid some quirks.

On the other hand, [ES5-DOM-SHIM](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM) seems to try to do too much and you currently want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which already ships methods that deal with DOM inconsistencies across browsers.

I would recommend you to just use jQuery and if you need to support the new HTML5 elements and/or custom elements, use the [HTML5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) (the defacto way to add HTML5 elements support on IE). If you really need ES5/6 shims, then use libraries with broader support from the community, like [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/) and [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/).